# WCF really wierd and unexpected behavior

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I have this `WCF Service Application` which contains 10-15 services. the services generally serve the same purpose but have different implementations. There was this one really simple method which was part of the soap service. The method basically looked like this

```
public Data GetData(string param1, string param2, string checksum)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Utilities.StringsAreEmpty(param1, param2, checksum)
            {
                throw new FaultException<ServiceFault>(){ ErrorCode = 1 };
            }

            var caller = Repository.GetProviders(param1);

            if (caller == null)
            {
                throw new FaultException<ServiceFault>(){ ErrorCode = 2 };
            }

            var realChecksum = Utilities.CalculateSha256Hash(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", param1, param2, caller.Key));

            if (realChecksum != checksum)
            {
                throw new FaultException<ServiceFault>(){ ErrorCode = 3 };
            }

            var data = Repository.GetData(param2);

            return data;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogException(ex);

            throw new FaultException<ServiceFault>(){ ErrorCode = 99 };
        }
    }
```

The method shown above worked perfectly, just as expected. after some time I had to modify some other service and after doing that and publishing the changes to the server (all those services are build into one .dll assembly So they cannot be deployed partially) this particular method started to behave really weirdly. I was not seeing any errors in Log and the method itself did not return anything at all. now first thing I did was removed `try catch` block, (I had this kind of problem before and removing `try catch` helped), and magically everything started working again. Now, I don't really see any problem in here and since I had this kind of issue for the second time now I am really concerned about it. Can somebody explain why does `try catch` removal work here ? first time I had this problem the internal server error occurred and the response from the server was absolutely nothing. not even an error HTML (returned by wcf) or anything like that. is this some kind of a bug with WCF ? or is it supposed to work this way ? if so, how can that be avoided ?

Comment: After you removed the try-catch block, can you create a dummy exception and log it? Is it possible that you have a problem with your exception logging?

Comment: no no there is no problem with exception logging, if there occurred some exception it was logged normally. I use that logging for my entire solution so there is practically no change at all that there is a problem with the exception logging. the logging method is really simple it just retrieves useful data from exception and writes it to the db.

Comment: Can you paste your real method into your question?

Comment: there you go. I just pasted the template

Comment: Your should enable WCF Tracing and add try catch block again. Then try a request and look in traces.svclog file. You should find the error there. I suspect there is something with the logging gathering the data to log, but there might be other reasons. If you enable the wcf tracing, run a test (with try/catch in place) and then investigate traces.svclog file and windows event log you should find the real error. Make sure the application pool has the right to write at the location of your traces.svclog file.

Comment: This is just a speculation, but I noticed your Catch block, that to my understanding when is compiled with the dll causes issues, throws an exception with error code 99, and the prior validations within the try block throws exceptions with error codes in range of 1-3.

Are you by any chance using some error handling mechanism, that handles the exception thrown according to the error code?

This may explain why the catch statement exception is filtered,